# let a,b,c are positive and less than 1 prove that 1-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)>k

Tags: real-analysis

Define $a, b, c$ such that $0<a, b, c<1$. Prove that $1-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)>k$ where $k=\max(a, b, c)$.

Comment: $where \max(a,b,c)$: what does this mean?

Comment: Of course, this means that we *must* pr ovethis there.

Answer (score 1):

Let a be the max(a,b,c).  (1-a)(1-b)(1-c) < (1-a) so that 1-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) > 1-(1-a)=a.

Comment: are you using the symbol $a$ for two potentially different quantities?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner No.  the question was about the max(a,b,c)=k.  For the proof I designated a=k, but the proof works just as well for  b=k or c=k, whichever is max.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for clarifying.  In other words, assume $a=\max(a,b,c)$ without loss of generality

Comment: Thx it's most helpful